# Elementary OS keeps on booting into a disabled administrator account

Tags: boot, greeter, user-interface, security

In order to better be able to administer my workstation which is used by the entire household I have set up one administrator account and took away administrator privileges for all the others. However there was a problem with administering the linuxbrew packages already installed on the system and so I disabled the account.

But instead of booting into the greeter the system boots straight into the disabled administrator account. That is a major security flaw. do you have any ideas how to rectify that and make Elementary boot directly into the greeter?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about your situation, but what I can recommend you is to check out this administrator account in System settings > User accounts - have you ticked in "log in automatically" for this account? Probably this is the reason why your computer log in into it automatically.

Comment: This was the first thing I checked, because I have done that for my main account. However I wanted to use the administrator account for maintenance only. The issue now seems to be fixed with one of the recent updates. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: I see. Can you put an answer with the way it was resolved and later accept it in order the question here to have an accepted answer?